# incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, string-matching

I was trying to pre allocate a variable to a matrix and in each loop I'm assigning a matrix(1 by 5) to a row in the matrix (5 by 5).

Here's the specific tables and code:

table1

```
  name   score  address 
 Jason   8      10 Cornell Street 
 Lisa    7     110 Park Avenue    
 David   10     225 Fifth Avenue
```

table 2

```
name    phone# 
David   323-4527 
Kudrow  233-3618
```

code

```
match_result=matrix("empty",ncol=5,nrow=5)
match_1=table1[,1]
match_2=table2[,1] 
match_split_1 <- str_split(match_1, pattern = " ")
match_split_2 <- str_split(match_2, pattern = " ")

k=1

for (i in 1:length(match_split_1)) 
  {
    for (j in 1:length(match_split_2))
    {
if (identical(match_split_12[[i]],match_split_22[[j]]))
{
 temp_result <- c(table1[i,], table2[j,])
match_result[k,] = t(as.matrix(temp_result))
k <- k+1
}
}
}
```

Here I've checked dim(t(as.matrix(temp_result))) returns [1] 1 5

> dim(match_result[1,])
>   NULL

Could anyone please point out how should I assign so it doesn't return 
Error in match_result[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Thank you!

Comment: Can I ask what the result is you're trying to achieve? Couldn't you do this with merge()?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Gabriel. The code I posed is a simplified version. The matching I'm doing is not exact matching so there are number of manipulation for the names before I enter the loop. Also, in the loop, there are multiple conditions that any of them satisfies would result in a match.So it's more like if {} else if{} else if{} Please let me know if I can still use merge. That'd save a great deal of time for me.

Comment: well you can merge on more than one column, so say you want to merge by name, but distinguish David with score 10 from David with score 6 you could merge by both columns (or more, as you need). If the names themselves are messy you can clean in advance (as I guess you are doing) or there are some useful edit-distance algorithms in the RecordLinkage package

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, Right now I'

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. Right now I don't want to differentiate David with 9 and David with 8. Say I have 2 rows in table2. with the same phone#. In table1 there is phone# as well. I want to match EITHER by name OR by phone#. Can merge do that? Thanks!